# Why StringBuilder does not print?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Why StringBuilder does not print what it should print in a small code

```
public final class Test1 {

    public void test() {
        System.out.println(setFin().toString());
    }

    protected StringBuilder setFin() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            builder.append("John");
            return builder.append("Ibrahim");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("In finaly");  // builder.append("-DarElBeida");
            builder = null;
        }
    }     

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Test1().test();
    }
}
```

In the last statement executed in `setFin()` (in the `finally` block) I have assigned `null` to `builder`, but my code prints `"In finally"` and then `"JohnIbrahim"`. Can anybody explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: This is atrocious code. Probably, you just want to read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When there is a `return` statement inside the `try` block, it will execute the `finally` block  before actually returning.

And the method doesn't return `null` because the `return` statement holds a reference to the actual *StringBuilder* object, not to the variable `builder`.

Setting `builder == null` doesn't delete the *StringBuilder* itself, it just drops `builder`'s reference to it.

This behavior can be confusing. To make things clear it could be helpful to return from outside the try/catch/finally block:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

try {
    builder.append("John");
    builder.append("Ibrahim");
} finally {
    System.out.println("In finaly");  // builder.append("-DarElBeida");
    builder = null;
}

return builder;
```

Comment: I think the OP is confused as to why it isn't printing `null`.

Comment: I think the confusion is about why this isn't printing `null` (which your statement doesn't really explain - it the `builder = null` is "evaluated before the return" then it "should return null" )

Answer (score 3):

You are returning `builder`.  After that you set `builder` to null. But it has already been returned. It does not matter what you do to the variable afterwards. The return value is already "locked-in". What you could do is mess with the object that is being returned. For example, `builder.setLength(0)` will remove all text to it.

In theory, you could also `return null` from the finally block, but that (changing the return value) is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

*Return* value is evaluated and stored on the *stack*, before the `finally` block runs. Note that the value on the stack is actually the value of the `StringBuilder` reference. So, even if you set the `builder` to `null`, that doesn't changes the evaluated `return` value already on the stack. However, if the return value is a reference to an mutable object, you can mutate the object, and the changes will be visible in `return` value.

For e.g., if you add the below statement in the `finally` block instead of `nullifying` the reference:

```
builder.append("Hrithik Roshan");
```

then you will see that content in the return value.

However, if you `return` the `builder` again, from `finally` block, it will overright the previous evaluated `return` statement. But mind you it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

`finally` is always executed, unless the JVM crashes or exits before the `try` block finishes.

If the `try` block completes due to a `return` statement, the expression of the `return` is evaluated into a single value *before* the `finally` block executes. That value is saved, and returned when the `finally` block completes.

Thus, the assignment of `builder = null` has no effect because the evaluation of `builder.append("Ibrahim")` is already finished by the time the `finally` executes.

Answer (score 1):

`builder` holds a reference to the StringBuilder that you've created.  When you do `builder = null`, you're setting `builder` to no longer hold that reference.  The StringBuilder itself still exists (at least until garbage collection occurs).

What's happening is that your `return` statement is returning a reference to the StringBuilder.  It's *not* returning the variable `builder`; it's returning a reference to the thing that `builder` refers to.  So even though you're wiping out the variable, the return statement already has a reference to the created object.

If you printed `builder` in your `finally` block, it would be null there.

Answer (score 0):

First executed `return` statement which  execute `builder.append("Ibrahim")` that returns the reference of `StringBuilder`. The referece is saved to the stack. Then excuted the `finally` block. You have nulled the local variable, but the reference to `StringBuilder` object passed to the caller after the method actually return. That's why printed all values. The error is that you assign a value to the `builder` in `finally` block that is never used. The stack keeps the value of the `return` statement operand before it actually returned, i.e. after `finally` block. If you don't want to return reference from the method you should `return null` in the `finally` block, that will override the value in the stack.

```
} finally {
  System.out.println("In finaly");  // builder.append("-DarElBeida");
  return null;

}
```